# Convert in XSD - private Map<String,List<abcType>> myMap

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xsd

How to convert a map containing of String and an user defined Type which defined in another xsd.

```
private Map <String,List<abcType>> myMap =null;
```

abcType.xsd is defined as -

```
<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:element name="abcType">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="myName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                        type="xyzType" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="xyzType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="KEY" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="VALUE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema
```

Comment: Convert what to what exactly? XML to Java? Java to XML?